# for loop to diff pairs of files

Tags: bash, diff

I have a script that logs in to around 30 pairs of routers. The script runs a command and saves the output to a file, then moves on to the next router and so on.

I now want to run a 'diff' on each pair of router's files and then 'diff' the next pair, etc. e.g. `diff rtr_1a rtr_1b` then `diff rtr_2a rtr_2b` and so on....

How do I tell 'diff' to only compare specific pairs of files without manually hard coding the names in multiple diff statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all files are called `rtr_ia` and `rtr_ib` for `i` between 1 and 30:

```
#!/bin/bash

for (( i = 1; i <= 30; ++i )); do
    diff "rtr_${i}a" "rtr_${i}b"
done
```

To save the diffs into files:

```
#!/bin/bash

for (( i = 1; i <= 30; ++i )); do
    diff "rtr_${i}a" "rtr_${i}b" >"rtr_${i}.diff"
done
```

---

After comments:

```
#!/bin/bash

for rtra in *rtr*a; do
   rtrb="${rtra%a}b"
   diff -- "$rtra" "$rtrb"
done
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash

for rtra in *rtr*a; do
   rtrb="${rtra%a}b"
   diff -- "$rtra" "$rtrb" >"${rtra}_${rtrb}.diff"
done
```

... to save to a file.

This matches all the `prefix-rtrNa` filenames and then, for each of these, creates the corresponding `prefix-rtrNb` filename (`${rtra%a}` will remove the trailing `a` from the value of `$rtra`).  It then diffs the two files.

Comment: That is helpful and may be a Plan B for me....however, I should have put a better example in my question. The naming convention for each pair has a unique 4-letter suffix, e.g.:
abcd-rtr1a
abcd-rtr1b
bcde-rtr1a
bcde-rtr1b

Comment: @machinist So you have multiple `prefix-rtr1a` and `prefix-rtr1b`?

Comment: correct and each 'prefix' differs for each pair - it's a site code basically